# emulation of scroll-off?

Tags: scrolling

Vim has an option called `scrolloff` (e.g. `set scrolloff=7`) which automatically scrolls down or up to keep the `cursor`/`point` from getting within a certain distance of the top or bottom of the window.

Is there a way to emulate this behavior in vanilla Emacs / evil mode? (preferably without advising every function that's capable of moving the point)

Emacs is capable of scrolling line by line (e.g. `C-u 1 C-v` and `C-u 1 M-v`), but the default behavior seems to be to scroll by full or half screens (maybe to limit the number of times that the entire screen needs to be updated?).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The variable `scroll-margin` controls this behaviour:

> Number of lines of margin at the top and bottom of a window.
>   Recenter the window whenever point gets within this many lines
>   of the top or bottom of the window.
>
> You can customize this variable.

By default, it is set to 0, but if you set it to 7 you'll get the behaviour you're describing.